# Error: `fsevents` unavailable (this watcher can only be used on Darwin) in CRA v2.1.7 and craco v3.5.0

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, create-react-app, fsevents

I am getting the above error while running jest v23 in a monorepo. The package i am running jest on is built on CRA and craco.
Package.json of my CRA

```
{
  "name": "@sprinklr/chat-web-client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/core": "^10.0.5",
    "@emotion/styled": "^10.0.5",
    "@sentry/browser": "^5.8.0",
    "@sentry/integrations": "^5.8.0",
    "@sprinklr/chat-constants": "2.0.0",
    "@sprinklr/chat-entities": "2.0.0",
    "@sprinklr/chat-utils": "2.0.0",
    "@sprinklr/rest-client": "2.0.0",
    "azure-storage": "^2.10.3",
    "bluebird": "^3.4.0",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "core-js": "^3.0.1",
    "emotion": "^10.0.2",
    "emotion-theming": "^10.0.5",
    "formik": "^1.3.2",
    "immutability-helper": "^2.8.1",
    "jstz": "^2.1.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "polished": "^2.3.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.5.7",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-autosize-textarea": "^6.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-frame-component": "^4.0.2",
    "react-redux": "7.2.0",
    "react-router": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.7",
    "react-transition-group": "^2.5.3",
    "react-use": "^14.1.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-saga": "^1.0.1",
    "reselect": "^4.0.0",
    "scriptjs": "^2.5.8",
    "shortid": "^2.2.14",
    "styled-system": "^3.0.2",
    "typesafe-actions": "^2.0.4",
    "validate.js": "^0.13.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "precommit": "pretty-quick --staged",
    "start": "sh internals/build/build-packages.sh && craco start --workspace",
    "prebuild": "NODE_ENV=production babel-node internals/build/tools/run prebuild",
    "build": "sh internals/build/build.sh",
    "analyze": "source-map-explorer build/static/js/main.*",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "docz:dev": "docz dev",
    "docz:build": "docz build",
    "static": "NODE_ENV=production babel-node internals/build/tools/run static/index",
    "widget": "NODE_ENV=production babel-node internals/build/tools/run widget/index",
    "i18n": "sh internals/i18n/index.sh",
    "lint": "eslint src",
    "format": "npm run prettier -- --write",
    "prettier": "prettier \"**/*.+(js|jsx|json|yml|yaml|css|less|scss|ts|tsx|md|graphql|mdx)\"",
    "validate": "npm run lint && npm run prettier -- --list-different",
    "test": "craco test --workspace --env=jsdom",
    "test-watch": "npm run test -- --watch",
    "test-coverage": "npm run test -- --coverage",
    "test-update": "npm run test -- --updateSnapshot"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "7.2.3",
    "@babel/core": "7.2.2",
    "@babel/node": "7.2.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.3.1",
    "@craco/craco": "^3.5.0",
    "@emotion/babel-preset-css-prop": "^10.0.7",
    "@sprinklr/chat-types": "2.0.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.4.0",
    "@types/bluebird": "^3.5.26",
    "@types/classnames": "^2.2.7",
    "@types/jest": "26.0.0",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.118",
    "@types/node": "^11.13.7",
    "@types/react": "^16.8.14",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.8.4",
    "@types/react-intl": "^2.3.15",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.0",
    "@types/react-router": "^4.4.2",
    "@types/react-textarea-autosize": "^4.3.3",
    "@types/react-transition-group": "^2.0.15",
    "@types/redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "@types/scriptjs": "^0.0.2",
    "@types/shortid": "^0.0.29",
    "@types/styled-system": "^3.0.8",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.392.0",
    "babel-plugin-lodash": "^3.3.4",
    "babel-plugin-named-asset-import": "^0.2.3",
    "babel-plugin-react-intl": "^3.0.1",
    "babel-plugin-react-intl-auto": "^1.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^7.0.0",
    "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.2",
    "docz": "^0.12.15",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^2.6.2",
    "glob": "^7.1.2",
    "husky": "^0.14.3",
    "node-sass-chokidar": "^1.3.0",
    "prettier": "1.13.7",
    "pretty-quick": "^1.6.0",
    "react-intl": "^2.8.0",
    "source-map-explorer": "^1.5.0",
    "terser": "3.16.1",
    "ts-jest": "26.1.1",
    "tslint": "^5.11.0",
    "tslint-config-prettier": "^1.16.0",
    "tslint-react-hooks": "^1.1.0",
    "typescript": "3.4.5",
    "typescript-styled-plugin": "^0.13.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.4"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "fsevents": "1.2.4"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">1%",
    "last 4 versions",
    "Firefox ESR",
    "not ie < 11"
  ]
}
```

I checked my node_modules and it has fsevents installed. Still getting the error. Most common solution which I found was reinstalling node_modules after deleting yarn.lock but this solution isn't working for me. Neither installing watchman worked.
I am using jestConfig of CRA itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this issue by installing brew and then doing
`brew install watchman`
on my mac.